# Can't enable RemindersDebugMenu in High Sierra

Tags: macos, calendar, high-sierra, notifications

```
defaults write com.apple.reminders RemindersDebugMenu -boolean true
```

doesn't work on High Sierra. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The debug menu can no longer be enabled in Reminders with High Sierra.